# WPF Add text to TextBlock based on property

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I have a `ListView` with a column that shows the state two letter appreviation. 
 Based on the value of a Boolean property (`HasWorkState`) I would like to add parenthesis around the state abbreviation when `HasWorkState = false`.

For instance:

- `HasWorkState = true` display `OH`
- `HasWorkState = false` display `(OH)`

The state abbreviation is displayed in a `GridViewColumn`:

```
<!-- Work State -->
<GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ActualWidth, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, 
                          Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=(x/10)*0.5}">
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content=" State"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WorkState}"
                       Style="{StaticResource StateStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

To this `GridViewColumn` I have applied this style:

```
<!-- Highlight missing work states -->
<Style x:Key="StateStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasWorkState}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding StringFormat=({0})}" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Work location unspecified. Using residence state." />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I know this style is being applied correctly as the `ToolTip` is being displayed when `HasWorkState = false`.  I just need to know how to add the parenthesis.  What I currently have for the `Text` value setter is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a solution, but it's worth knowing why you had the problem: Because you're setting `Text` with an attribute on the TextBlock element, the style can't override that. If you used a style setter to apply the default `{Binding WorkState}`, the style would be able to override it.

I prefer to keep things like this in the view, so my approach would be this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding WorkState}" Style="{StaticResource StateStyle}" />
```

State style:

```
<Style x:Key="StateStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasWorkState}" Value="False">
            <!-- Leave the content alone and just change the format string -->
            <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="({0})" />

            <Setter 
                Property="ToolTip" 
                Value="Work location unspecified. Using residence state." 
                />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually prefer this method as it keeps all the display related changes in XAML.

Comment: @BrianKE Did you get it working? I was just setting up a test project.

Comment: I did, there was a typo in the style that was causing the issue.  Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @BrianKE Not at all. I hadn't tested it, which is always a risk.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to add that property to your view model. Something like this in your view model:

```
internal class StateStyleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool hasWorkState;
    private string workState;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string WorkState
    {
        get { return workState; }
        set
        {
            if (value == workState) return;
            workState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            //Notify that the value of the dependent property has changed.
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayWorkState));
        }
    }

    public bool HasWorkState
    {
        get { return hasWorkState; }
        set
        {
            if (value == hasWorkState) return;
            hasWorkState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            //Notify that the value of the dependent property has changed.
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayWorkState));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property for binding
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayWorkState => HasWorkState ? WorkState : $"({WorkState})";

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then you just bind to DisplayWorkState instead of WorkState

Comment: Clever solution!  Never thought about applying the lambda operator in this manner.